# Analytic Solution for an Infinite Sum Involving 1F2 Hypergeometric Function with parameters whose difference is one half

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I am attempting to find an analytic solution for the following infinite sum, where $x$ is a nonnegative real number:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k y^{2k} k}{(2k)!} \, {}_1F_2\left(k+1;2,k+\frac{1}{2};-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)
\end{equation}

The series involves a generalized hypergeometric function $ {}_1F_2 $ with these specific parameters. While I have come across integral representations that involve $ {}_0F_2 $ hypergeometric functions, they haven't led to any useful simplification of the sum.

My main objective is to find an analytic solution to this infinite sum. Does anyone know of a specific integral representation, identity, or transformation for this $ {}_1F_2 $ function that would facilitate solving the sum analytically?

Any pointers, insights, or references would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can factor out the hypergeometric function since it does not depend on $k$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I made the edit correcting that.